# strip out VT100 control characters from a log file

Tags: log-files, color

I've got a file that's full of VT100 color codes, which is making it hard to search. Is there a unix utility that can strip those out so I'm left with plain text?

Comment: Trying to cleanup the output of a `script` run? I remember there was a script that did exactly this on some system I used to have access to... I think it was the University of Waterloo Math Department's Unix machines. But I think some clever bastard there wrote it a while ago. Find a friend still at UW :)

Answer (score 1):

Try catting it through `col -b`

cat file | col -b

This works for stripping the troff/nroff formatting for man pages.  Worth a try.

If that doesn't work, there's quite a good thread on perlmonks:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=132997

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
esc=$'\033'
sed "s/${esc}[^m]*m//g" inputfile
```

Comment: `sed s/$'\033'[^m]*m//g` works like a charm for me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the strings command possibly!

Comment: I tried that, it leaves a bunch of [01;34m strings

Comment: ok then pipe it to sed with the appropriate edits and yes there's got to be a better way.